# Get proceeding lines after match until lines match other pattern

Tags: java, regex

The story - extract info from log files - in this case maven build. Basically I want to get all lines that match a pattern after a given pattern is matched first.

In other words I want to match all lines that starts with `[WARNING]` after the `[WARNING] Javadoc Warnings` line.

I tried using this:

```
(?<=\[WARNING\] Javadoc Warnings).*(\r|\n|.)(?=(\[WARNING\].*))
```

but it only returns the next lines.

```
[WARNING] E:\workspaces\1
[WARNING] E:\workspaces\4
```

**input:**

```
[WARNING] E:\workspaces\asd
[WARNING] E:\workspaces\dsa

[INFO] 
12 warnings
[WARNING] Javadoc Warnings
[WARNING] E:\workspaces\1
[WARNING] E:\workspaces\2
[WARNING] E:\workspaces\3

[INFO] Building jar: E:\workspaces\asdf
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:j

[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:j
[INFO] 
12 warnings
[WARNING] Javadoc Warnings
[WARNING] E:\workspaces\4
[WARNING] E:\workspaces\5
[WARNING] E:\workspaces\6
[INFO] Building jar: E:\workspaces\asdf
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:j
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:j
```

and the desired result is

```
[WARNING] E:\workspaces\1
[WARNING] E:\workspaces\2
[WARNING] E:\workspaces\3
[WARNING] E:\workspaces\4
[WARNING] E:\workspaces\5
[WARNING] E:\workspaces\6
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't think this is a duplicate. The answers explain how to match between two strings. In my scenario I try to match after given match until the lines fulfill another pattern

Comment: Between two strings vs after `^` and before another string, principally, they're the same thing.

Comment: Ok, I think I see the point. What is the tool you are using?

Comment: @ctwheels may be the case for you but I don't find it similar. I really try to find answers before I post, unfortunately I'm stuck.

Comment: [`(?<=\[WARNING\] Javadoc Warnings|\G(?!\A))\s*\K\[WARNING\].*`](https://regex101.com/r/E3MQVD/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `grep` (cigwin) or java, it doesn't matter. But I guess I'd manage to build it from a working demo

Comment: @mihail it's not always necessarily true that you can build it from a working demo. The regex I just presented works in PCRE flavours of regex but will not in most other flavours.

Comment: In Java, [`(?:\[WARNING\] Javadoc Warnings|\G(?!\A))\r?\n(\[WARNING\].*)`](https://regex101.com/r/fXTB7d/1) will work, just grab `group(1)`.

Comment: @ctwheels your example works at https://regex101.com/ - it's really enough for. You can post it as an answer and I'd like to accept it. The examination is my job now.

Comment: It works, yes, but not for your flavour of regex. Wiktor's answer is the correct one for your regex engine.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you could post this as answer too. It would be helpful for other people. I see I was missing (and don't know about) some modifiers. Thank you both.

Comment: Modifiers are different from tokens. Modifiers/flags set options on the regex as a whole (unless you specify them inside a token using something like `(?i)`).Tokens are the pieces that make up the larger regular expression. Tokens may act differently depending on modifiers (both global and inline modifiers)

Comment: I wonder if `grep -zoP '(?:\[WARNING\] Javadoc Warnings|\G(?!\A))\s*\K\[WARNING\].*'` will work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew on `cigwin` - no, I don't even have the -o and -P there. I will play around when I have the time and give you feedback for sure.

Comment: Yeah, true, Cygwin implementation is too limited. Use Java then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following solution:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\[WARNING] Javadoc Warnings)\R(\[WARNING].*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fXTB7d/1)

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|\[WARNING] Javadoc Warnings)` - a `[WARNING] Javadoc Warnings` substring (`\[WARNING] Javadoc Warnings`) or (`|`) the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!\A)`)
- `\R` - a line break
- `(\[WARNING].*)` - Group 1: `[WARNING]` substring and any 0+ chars after it to the end of the line

See the [online Java demo](https://ideone.com/PaYGJK):

```
String s = "[WARNING] E:\\workspaces\\asd\r\n[WARNING] E:\\workspaces\\dsa\r\n\r\n[INFO] \r\n12 warnings\r\n[WARNING] Javadoc Warnings\r\n[WARNING] E:\\workspaces\\1\r\n[WARNING] E:\\workspaces\\2\r\n[WARNING] E:\\workspaces\\3\r\n\r\n[INFO] Building jar: E:\\workspaces\\asdf\r\n[INFO] \r\n[INFO] >>> maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:j\r\n\r\n[INFO] \r\n[INFO] <<< maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:j\r\n[INFO] \r\n12 warnings\r\n[WARNING] Javadoc Warnings\r\n[WARNING] E:\\workspaces\\4\r\n[WARNING] E:\\workspaces\\5\r\n[WARNING] E:\\workspaces\\6\r\n[INFO] Building jar: E:\\workspaces\\asdf\r\n[INFO] \r\n[INFO] >>> maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:j\r\n[INFO] \r\n[INFO] <<< maven-source-plugin:3.0.1:j";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:\\G(?!\\A)|\\[WARNING] Javadoc Warnings)\\R(\\[WARNING].*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Probably one stupid question - is there a reason for not escaping the `]` characters?

Comment: @mihail: A `]` outside a character class has no special meaning, there is no need escaping regular chars that only denote themselves in a regex pattern. The fewer backslashes, the less confusion it creates. But you may escape `]` if you are not confident with regexps.